# Can Play! Framework compile on the fly in production mode?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I tried to `Ctrl+D` after launching the app, then launching `play` again and executing `compile`, but then compilation works but changes are not applied automatically.

So my question is, if it can compile and apply changes on the fly, how can it be done? If not, what is the best way to compile and push changes without having to stop the application for a few seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It can't and it shouldn't.

For keeping application working without any pause you need to run temporary second instance and handle load balancing using some front-end HTTP server